# create file in a different location

Tags: wordpress

I want to with wordpress create a page in a different location of common wordpress posts and pages, like this: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
and yet I want use WP Loop and all of wordpress functions
please help me

Comment: Please help us help you - provide a clear and complete description of what you want to do, and what you have tried and didn't work.

Comment: @lettersandblankspaces Yes, I want all wp functions, If I don't want then I use pure php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call "wp functions" at the beginning of your file using

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset: UTF-8');
require( '../../../../wp-load.php' );
```

where ../../ ...  is the path to your `wp-load.php` file depending on where you put it.

After this, you can use loop the way you like.

Comment: I don't say that you downvote, I ask you that my question is bad?