# Wordpress categories taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, categories, taxonomy

I`m using ACF plugin for custom fields and categories made from the plugin. My problem is that I made a custom category called "Mobile". Adding a new custom post and inserting it in the category "Mobile" from admin dashboard works.

But if i`m trying to to set the post to that category from code with `wp_set_object_terms` it gives me an error with invalid taxonomy. I have looked for a solution to my situation but the only thing that is important that the taxonomy to be loaded before i call it. I don`t know where to look in the ACF plugin or my plugin to see what`s wrong.

Can you give me an advice?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by custom category?

Comment: Categories made from the ACF plugin. Sorry, i will edit the question to not create further confusion.

Comment: to be brief, a taxonomy is a group of terms, for example, the name of the taxonomy of default post type is "categories". If you have under  "categories" : "health", "sport", "litterature"...thoses are the terms of "categories" taxonomy. When you create a custom post type, you should create a taxonomy first then create its terms.  I hope my comment is not wasting your time, but I always emphasize in remembering this to others, since me too I was mistaken.

Comment: can you please write the full line containing wp_set_object_terms?

Comment: I understand, and is not wasting my time, thank you very much for taking the time and answer to me, the problem is that all my taxonomies are registered by the ACF plugin and in one part of the plugin to register my post in the taxonomy category works, but when i do from another file in the same plugin it fails and gives me the error specified in the question.

Comment: I tried to understand but in vain, what do you mean by another file in the same plugin? maybe you need to call the Wordpress core in this file using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976765/create-file-in-a-different-location/15976936#15976936.... But the best thing is to post some code here.

Comment: `wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $categories, 'mobile_cat' );` - this don`t want to work. Where the categories is an array with id of categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the usage of `wp_set_object_terms()` function. The second parameter should contain the id or slug of the term to add, in your case, it should be the slug or the  id related to 'mobile_cat'. Then the third parameter should specify the taxonomy where to add this term. In your post  still don't know what is your taxonomy name.

You can get all the required info from database.

good luck

Comment: Added the slug, worked like a charm. Thank you very much. But is also odd that with slug works, and on id doesn`t. But important is that works